Removed the set screw, but the handle fixture will not lift off. I have tried prying it, but with no luck
The fixture is a Delta 2 handle bathroom fixture installed in 2004.  I've watched the tutorials and they indicate the handle should lift right off.  Not happening! Suggestions?

It's been stuck on for 20 years, it needs some force and persuasion.

there are many variant, so without picture we can not continue

Might need a puller and slide hammer to persuade it.
